# Is there collator alternative to unicodeStr1.caseCompare(unicodeStr2, U_FOLD_CASE_DEFAULT)?

Tags: c++, unicode, collation, icu

I have following code:

```
auto unicodeStr1 = icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF8(utf8Str1);
auto unicodeStr2 = icu::UnicodeString::fromUTF8(utf8Str2);
return unicodeStr1.caseCompare(unicodeStr2, U_FOLD_CASE_DEFAULT);
```

that I want to refactor to use collator (omit status checks):

```
UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
std::unique_ptr<icu::Collator> collator(icu::Collator::createInstance(status));
collator->setStrength(icu::Collator::PRIMARY); // make case insensitive
return collator->compareUTF8(utf8Str1, utf8Str2, status);
```

All fine but some of unit tests of big project that I works on start to fail, e.g. I found out that `caseCompare` variant gives order "test-test" < "test_test" while `compareUTF8` gives "test_test" < "test-test".

What is equivalent of `unicodeStr1.caseCompare(unicodeStr2, U_FOLD_CASE_DEFAULT)` in terms of collator?

Comment: Got some examples of these failing tests for testing?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's legacy project and I could not understand what this tests do and why they fail XD

Comment: I found out that `caseCompare` variant gives `"test-test" < "test_test"` while `compareUTF8` gives `"test_test" < "test-test"`